# Double the value of each array element using Reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have array of elements as input.all I need is to double the value of array elements.Though it is simple to make use of **map** to get the solution.I am interested in using reduce.eg:
io: var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
op:[2,4,6,8,10]; .but this is where I ended.

```
var c = a.reduce( (acc,b) => {
           acc =b*2;
           console.log(acc);
           return acc 
         },[]);
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: `[1,2,3].reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x * 2), [])`, but please, use `map`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var doubled = arr.reduce(function (memo, val) {
  memo.push(val * 2);
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(doubled);

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr2.reduce(function (memo, val, i) {
  memo[i] *= 2;
  return memo;
}, arr2);

console.log(arr2);

var arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr3.reduce(function (memo, val, i) {
  arr3[i] *= 2;
}, null);

console.log(arr3);
```

In the first solution, `reduce` starts with an empty array (the second argument provided to it). Then, that array is passed down to next iterations as the first argument (`memo`) to the function we provided. The second argument is the current element of the iteration. After the doubled value is pushed in the new array, that array is returned so it can be accessed in future iterations as `memo`.

In the second solution, no new array is created and the initial one is used instead. It is passed to `reduce` as its second element and later accessed through `memo`.

The third solution is like the second one except the reduced array is just referenced as it is. Notice that `null` must be passed as second argument. If nothing is passed, `reduce` will start from the second element (since there's no initial value) and the first element won't get doubled.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**
The first time the callback is called, accumulator and currentValue can be one of two values. If no initialValue is provided, then accumulator will be equal to the first value in the array, and currentValue will be equal to the second.

```
let arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    arrayOfNumbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
     //code
    },initialvalue);
```

if you miss this initialvalue argument then your index begins from one(1) and the accumulator will have the first value of array.
Hence your array[index] = array[index]*2
For example in such case

arr=[1,2,3,4,5]

output
arr=[1,4,6,8,10]

Now this will be the approach

```
   let arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    arrayOfNumbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
      console.log(accumulator,currentValue);
      array[index] = array[index]*2;
    },0);
```

arr=[1,2,3,4,5]

output
arr=[1,4,6,8,10]

take initialvalue as 0(or any value), so that you can get the index from 0.
if you do this accumulator will get 0 and the index begins from 0 only.

**Note**
if you don't initialize accumulator value that is initialvalue.
Default
accumulator(initialvalue) will be arr[0]
and index begins from 1

and

if you initialize accumulator value that is initialvalue(argument) then
accumulator(initialvalue) will take that initialvalue and index begins from 0.

Answer (score 0):

As you provided in your last parameter to reduce, `acc` is an array, although you're treating it like an integer. You'll want something like below:

```
var c = a.reduce( (acc,b) => {
       acc.push(b*2);
       console.log(acc);
       return acc 
     },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var c = a.reduce( (acc,b) => acc.concat(b*2) 
         ,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a couple other answers that aren't shown here

**1. Using spread syntax**

```js
const data =
  [1,2,3,4,5];

const double = xs =>
  xs.reduce ((ys, x) => [...ys, x * 2], [])
  
console.log(double(data))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
```

**2. Using a destructured parameter with recursion**

```js
const data =
  [1,2,3,4,5]

// this time we don't need reduce
const double = ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined ? [] : [x * 2, ...double(xs)]

console.log(double(data))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
```

**3. Tacit (Point-free style)**

```js
const data =
  [1,2,3,4,5]

const mult = x => y =>
  y * x

const reduce = f => acc => ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined 
    ? acc
    : reduce (f) (f (acc, x)) (xs)
    
const map = f =>
  reduce ((acc, x) =>
    [...acc, f (x)]) ([])

// point-free double
const double =
  map (mult (2))

console.log (double (data))
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
```